# How do I remove mate desktop completely?

Tags: linux-mint, apt, cinnamon, mate-desktop

I have installed Linux Mint Cinnamon 17.3 64 bit. I had installed mate desktop on the top of it. I want to remove mate desktop completely. I tried apt-get purge and autoremove, but mate is shown in login manager. How can I completely get rid of it?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to uninstall with apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get uninstall mate-*
```

Or:

```
sudo apt-get remove mate-*
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: Returns : Invalid operation uninstall, remove, purge and auto remove all three tried

Comment: `sudo apt-get remove mate-*` worked for me (Linux Mint 20).

Answer (score 0):

```
dpkg --purge mate-* --force-all
```